# Numpy reshape an array with specific order

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

Let's say I have this array x:

```
x = array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
x.shape = (8,1)
```

I want to reshape it to become

```
array([[1, 3, 5, 7], 
       [2, 4, 6, 8]])
```

this is a reshape(2, 4) on x but in the straight forward way:

```
y = x.reshape(2,4)
```

y becomes

```
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8]])
```

and that's not what I want. Is there a way to transform the array in that specific way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
In[4]: x.reshape(4, 2).T
Out[4]: 
array([[1, 3, 5, 7],
       [2, 4, 6, 8]])
```

Comment: Transpose!! Awesome.tks

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do this is to specify the `order`argument in `reshape` function.

---

**You need the Fortran order.**

*Side note: Matlab by default is using Fortran order but in python you need to specify that.*

---

**Use this:**

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
y = x.reshape(2,4, order='F')

print(y)
#array([[1, 3, 5, 7],
#       [2, 4, 6, 8]])
```

Comment: This is interesting, as I was trying to replicate some results I had in Matlab, and couldn't get the same in Python when I was reshaping. It took a long time until I considered that the ordering was different!

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use the option `order='F'` to your reshape-call like

```
res = numpy.reshape(my_array, (2,4), order='F')
```

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do:

```
y = np.array([x[0::2], x[1::2]])
```